# Different issues with HttpsURLConnection with different Android versions

Tags: android, http

I'm writing app using SOAP. So I'm using HttpsURLConnection for HTTPS. Everything was working quite fine when I had HTC Hero with Gingerbread. But now I have Nexus S with ICS, and I'm always getting 401 response, but credentials are fine, and Authenticator.setDefault() is called. And in Froyo my boss has, I get 400 or 500, and it's pretty random. What the f...?

Current source code: http://pastebin.com/baTY98K5

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced some problems using HttpUrlConnection with the GingerBread (used to work fine with the earlier versions, the same code).
I migrated to HttpClient and it worked for me always.
I am not sure whats the problem is with HttpUrlConnection, but yes this approach worked.
If somebody has the better solution that makes the HttpUrlConnection work, please tell.
Else I would suggest to migrate to HttpClient.